# Foundation ZURB custom form select option error

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Foundation Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to create a web application. I use custom forms to style select areas and on some of the pages that I have the select fields are doing this:
[image: error]
When they should look like this:
[image: normal state]

Code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <!-- country -->
        <div class="error-spacer">
            <span class="form-error-message" id="country_error">&nbsp;</span>
            <p>
                <select id="country" name="country" title="Country">
                    <option value="">Country</option>
                    <option data-list="united-states-list" value="United States">United States</option> 
                    <option data-list="united-kingdom-list" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                    <option data-list="australia-list" value="Australia">Australia</option> 
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /country -->

    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <!-- region -->
        <div class="error-spacer">
            <span class="form-error-message" id="region_error">&nbsp;</span>
            <p>
                <select id="region" name="region" title="Region">
                    <option value="">Please Select Country</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /region -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping your code in a `<form class="custom">` tag and initializing Foundation ZURB works as expected I guess. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLXqH/). You must have some custom CSS of your own breaking it. Check with your browser development tools.

Comment: Yes it was a rule i had messing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be some custom css interfering with Foundation's CSS.